# How to structure complex query

Tags: python, sql, r

I have three databases in a sql database that look like this:

D: Location of dealers

```
dealer:    zip:      affiliate:
 AAA       32313      Larry
 BBB       32322      John
```

O: Sales record

```
customer:               affiliate:      zip:       count:
John's Construction     Larry          35331       3
Bill's Sales            John           12424       300
Jim's Searching         Larry          14422       32
```

Z: Zip distance database

```
zip1:         zip2:          dist:
35235         35235          20
32355          15553         14
```

I am trying to look at Database D (a list of dealers and their location), and see how much their estimated sales are. I am doing this by using Database O, which shows all sales to customers, as well as their location. The logic we are working with is, for each dealer, look through the Database O and find the zip that minimizes distance. We will assume that the dealer that was located closest to the sale was the one who made the sale.

I am having a lot of trouble setting up the SQL query to do this, and am wondering if SQL is even the right place to do this. I know a little python, and a good amount of R. Any help is appreciated.

The query I am currently using:

```
SELECT d.rowid, d.dealer, d.affiliate, o.count, MIN(z.dist)
FROM database D, database O, zip z
WHERE d.Zip = z.zip1 AND o.zip = z.zip2
GROUP BY d.rowid
```

Comment: I am just trying to understand. So you are finding the dealer close to each customer based on zip table?

Comment: @Valli that is correct. Find the dealer closest to each customer, find out how much that dealer sold. The query I have above is returning a number FAR too small to be right.

Comment: @Valli the part I am having trouble with is, I need SQL to grab the customer, the customer's ZIP, and then the closest ZIP code from the dealer table, And I am having trouble getting it to do that last part

Comment: How do you match dealers table with sales record? Do you match with affiliate?

Comment: @Santosh, that is the problem, we have nothing to match on, so we are pairing the dealer table with the sales record by whichever pair of sales and dealer combo minimizes ZIP distance.

Comment: Then how would you join the tables to find the sales record? Are you trying to match zip of sales record with zip in location of dealers?

Comment: I wrote the query but I do not understand what are you looking for?

Comment: @Santosh, Think of it this way. Customer A lives 10 miles from Dealer A, he lives 20 miles from dealer B, and 500 miles from Dealer C. Therefore, we would pair the customer with dealer A since he lives closest to that dealer, and assign that customers sales to Dealer A.

It isnt necessarily matching on zip (not all sales locations will match exactly with a dealer location). Rather, its finding for each customer, the dealer with the minimum distance, and assigning it that way.

Comment: How would you make the connection from Customer to Dealer? Based on common zip? If its not then you can not approach this problem by sql query. Because sql is about relational data.

Comment: @Santosh that may be the issue, the relation from customer to dealer would be made by taking each customer, calculating the distance he has from each dealer, and then selecting the dealer with the smallest distance. Is this possible, or do I need to look into python?

Comment: You need to have a common elements between the tables. If its not then you need something else. I do not understand why you even have a zip in every table. From tables it seems that you need to choose minimum distance based on zip.

Comment: @Santosh, that is correct.

Comment: See my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your test data to test the sql query in R. I used `sqldf` library in R.

```
## Your Modified Test Data
LocationOfDealers <- data.frame(dealer = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"), zip = c(32313, 32322, 35235), affiliate = c("Larry", "John", "Larry"))    

SalesRecord <- data.frame(customer=c("John's Construction", "Bill's Sales", "Jim's Searching", "Tim's Sales"), affiliate = c("Larry", "John", "Larry", "James"), zip = c(35331, 12424, 14422, 35235), count = c(3, 300, 32, 20))

ZipDistance <- data.frame(zip1=c(35235, 32355), zip2=c(35235, 15553), dist = c(20, 14))

#LocationOfDealers
#   dealer   zip   affiliate
#1    AAA   32313     Larry
#2    BBB   32322      John
#3    CCC   35235     Larry    

# SalesRecord
#         customer       affiliate      zip   count
# 1 John's Construction     Larry     35331     3
# 2        Bill's Sales      John     12424   300
# 3     Jim's Searching     Larry     14422    32
# 4         Tim's Sales     James     35235    20

#  ZipDistance
#   zip1  zip2 dist
# 1 35235 35235   20
# 2 32355 15553   14

## Sql query in R using sqldf
library(sqldf)
sqldf({"
    SELECT dealer, MIN(dist) as Min_Dist, SUM(count) as dealer_Sold FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM LocationOfDealers D
      INNER JOIN ZipDistance Z on
      D.zip = Z.zip1
      INNER JOIN SalesRecord O on
      O.zip = Z.zip2) GROUP BY dealer 
"})

### There is only one dealer with common Zip between customer and dealers, and its min distance is 20
#  dealer Min_Dist dealer_Sold
#1    CCC       20          20
```

Comment: Will try out shortly and report back! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just to tell you, I updated my code (Earlier I missed `GROUP BY` statement).

Comment: will this sum values where a customer placed multiple separate orders with a dealer?

Comment: No. Since you did not mention in your question. But, you can do `SUM(count)` in first select statement.

Comment: thanks, I am running it but it is taking a while to run! The location of dealers has 1700 observatoins, the sales has 44000 observations, and my zip code data has 1.9M observations

Comment: sadly, the output sums to a number that is a few thousand greater than the count that is being inputted. Something is wrong

Comment: Maybe there are duplicates. So you can select `distinct` rows I think. I don't have your data. So, can't tell anything. It gave perfect results when I even extended some of your data when I tested SUM.